# Best way to navigate between records in a text file?

Tags: vb.net, text-files, record

I must use records in text files for my college project and be able to navigate between them. This is easy enough, I have a forward and back arrow set of buttons and can easily navigate between by +1 or -1 to the record number parameter.

However when I delete a file [Copy all records to a different file, except the one I want to delete, and then rename the different file to the main file], it goes all wacky and doesn't understand that a record is missing, or what record number to assign it.

Is there an easier way to navigate records in a text file? VB.NET 2017.

Comment: Is it a requirement to use text files? A database would be more convenient.

Comment: I think it's preferred, as I've only been taught how to do this with text files. I haven't done a database yet, will that require a lot of knowledge of VB?

Comment: Also mate, this is the only thing I'm missing in regards to doing this project with text files. I've got the rest of the program functioning, the issue is just navigation.

Comment: Sorry, but neither I nor anyone here will be able to provide good help unless you post the code causing the problem, and explain the problem in detail.  "Goes all wacky" is not a problem we can reproduce in our dev environments.

Comment: You’re probably best to be doing something like loading the entire file into some in memory collection that way moving between records is easy, with out some context though really hard to give you any real solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Records As New List(Of String)
Private CurrentRecordIndex As Integer = 0
Private CurrentRecord As String = ""

Private Sub LoadRecords(FilePath As String)
    Records = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).ToList()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveRecords(FilePath As String)
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, Records)
End Sub

Private Enum Direction
    Down
    Up
End Enum

Private Sub NavigateRecords(ByVal Direction As Direction)
    If Direction = Direction.Down Then
        If CurrentRecordIndex < Records.Count - 1 Then
            CurrentRecordIndex += 1
            CurrentRecord = Records(CurrentRecordIndex)
        End If
    Else
        If CurrentRecordIndex > 0 Then
            CurrentRecordIndex -= 1
            CurrentRecord = Records(CurrentRecordIndex)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveCurrentRecord()
    Records.RemoveAt(CurrentRecordIndex)
End Sub
```

I loaded the items into a list which is much easier than trying to save to the text file for each operation. You can load the `records` into the list, by calling the `LoadRecords` sub, and once you have made edits to the list you can run the `SaveRecords` sub, which will save the list to the text file. When the `NavigateRecords` sub is called, the current record moved either up or down, depending on the `Direction` specified in the argument. And when the `RemoveCurrentRecord` is invoked, the current record is removed from the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great descriptions and the suggestion of using a list. I'll learn to use a list now, but I'm uncertain how the list will differentiate between records? Here is my input of my variables into the text file and where it will all be outputted: https://imgur.com/a/6z2CUyX